# How to add value to the Mysql table using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have written a code to insert the values into the database table using ajax. If u see the image below ,the values are appeared in the text boxes and when pressed add areas button, these values must be added to the table.

image:
[image]

From the image, the values of X,Y,W and H are gathered and when the add areas button is clicked, it should insert the values of x,y,w and h in the table.

index.php:

```
<table>
          <tr>
          <div class="actions">

          <input type="button" id="btnView" value="Display areas" class="actionOn" />

          <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" class="actionOn" />
          <input type="button" id="btn_add" value="add areas" class="actionOn" />


        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="output" class='output'> </div>
</table>
          <p>X:<input type= "text" id="x" name ="x" value="-">
          <p>Y:<input type= "text" id="y" name ="y" value="-">
          <p>W:<input type= "text" id="w" name ="w" value="-">
          <p>H:<input type= "text" id="h" name ="h" value="-">


  <script>
  var selectionExists;

  function areaToString (area) {
      document.getElementById('x').value = area.x;
      document.getElementById('y').value = area.y;

      document.getElementById('w').value = area.width;
      document.getElementById('h').value = area.height;

    return (typeof area.id === "undefined" ? "" : (area.id + ": ")) + area.x + ':' + area.y  + ' ' + area.width + 'x' + area.height + '<br />'
  }


  $('#btn_add').click(function(){
    var x_value= document.getElementById('x').value;
    var y_value= document.getElementById('y').value;
    var w_value= document.getElementById('w').value;
    var h_value= document.getElementById('h').value;
    $.ajax({
                      type:'POST',
                      url: 'server.php',
                      data:{
                        'x_value': x_value,
                        'y_value': y_value,
                        'w_value': w_value,
                        'h_value': h_value
                      },
                      success: function(data){
                        alert("x:" + x_value +"y:" +y_value+"w:" +w_value+"h:" +h_value);
                      }
  });
});

  function output (text) {
    $('#output').html(text);
  }

  // Log the quantity of selections
  function debugQtyAreas (event, id, areas) {
    console.log(areas.length + " areas", arguments);
  };

  // Display areas coordinates in a div
  function displayAreas (areas) {
    var text = "";
    $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
      text += areaToString(area);
    });
    output(text);
  };
  </script>
```

Server.php:

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project_focus');
    if(isset($_POST['x_value'])){
    $x= $_POST['x_value'];
    $valid="SELECT * FROM sample";
    $validdb=mysqli_query($db, $valid);
    while (mysqli_fetch_array($validdb)){
    $add_x= "INSERT INTO sample (x_value) VALUES ($x)";
    mysqli_query($db, $add_x);
    }
      }
     ?>
```

The database table name is sample and its fields are id, x_value, y_value , w, h.

The server.php is the file where i tried to use the mysql query to insert the values into the table. but when i run the code, the output is not achieved. The insert values did not work. I think i made some mistake with the query i think. but i couldnt figure it out. Can someone help me fix this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have your database connection in a folder that is being `$_POST` to. Keep your connection in a folder with permissions set to 700, then require the file into another page that is alright to `$_POST` to. Learn AJAX too.

Comment: @StackSlave I don't understand, can u explain me with example

Comment: It's like... where do I start? That fetch looks bad too. You never assign it to a variable, even. How would you get the row? I'm going to also recommend that you learn the Object Oriented style of PHP. It'll save you a bunch of keystrokes.

Comment: @StackSlave okay, i will check those things, but can u help me to insert the value into table now ?

Comment: You never attempt an `INSERT`. You can't `UPDATE` an non-existent record.

Comment: i edited the code with insert query

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (other than the fact you're only inserting the `x_value` and nothing else). What debugging have you done? Have you checked your browser's _Network_ console to ensure the right data is being posted to the right URL? If so, is the response successful? Have you bothered finding out how to check for errors thrown by your PHP script?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to remove the while clause?

You shouldn't need to first query the database in order to do the insert.  Just executing the connect and insert commands should work.

Be sure that the other columns in the table are not required, and are set as DEFAULT NULL, so that the query doesn't error on other columns not being set in your insert.

```
$add_x= "INSERT INTO sample (x_value) VALUES ($x)";
mysqli_query($db, $add_x);
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML, CSS, and JavaScript should be more like

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// magic below
const x = I('x'), y = I('y'), w = I('w'), h = I('h'), display = I('display');
const reset = I('reset'), add = I('add'), error = I('error');
function valid(){
  let xv = x.value, yv = y.value, wv = w.value, hv = h.value;
  if(xv === '' || isNaN(xv) || yv === '' || isNaN(yv) || wv === '' || isNaN(wv) || hv === '' || isNaN(hv)){
    error.textContent = 'Invalid Number';
    return  false;
  }
  error.textContent = ''; return true;
}
x.oninput = y.oninput = w.oninput = h.oninput = ()=>{
  valid();
}
display.onclick = ()=>{
  const fd = new FormData; fd.append('get_xywh', true);
  post('xywh.php', fd, data=>{
    output.innerHTML = '';
    data.xywh.forEach(o=>{
      const sect = M('div'), sx = M('div'), sy = M('div'), sw = M('div');
      const sh = M('div');
      sx.textContent = 'X: '+o.x; sy.textContent = 'Y: '+o.y; 
      sw.textContent = 'W: '+o.w; sh.textContent = 'H: '+o.h; sect.appendChild(sx);
      sect.appendChild(sy); sect.appendChild(sw); sect.appendChild(sh);
      output.appendChild(sect);
    });
  });
}
reset.onclick = ()=>{
  x.value = y.value = 0; w.value = h.value = 1; error.textContent = '';
}
add.onclick = ()=>{
  if(valid()){
    const fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('x', x.value); fd.append('y', x.value); fd.append('w', w.value); 
    fd.append('h', h.value);
    post('xywh.php', fd, json=>{
      error.textContent = json.success ? 'Hacker' : 'Content Added';
    });
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; 
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
.er{
  color:#900;
}
#xywh{
  display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; align-content:top center; 
}
#xywh>*{
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
#xywh>label{
  flex:0 5%; text-align:center; padding-top:3px;
}
input{
  padding:3px 5px; border:0;
}
input[type=number]{
  border-radius:3px;
}
#xywh>input{
  flex:0 95%;
}
.main{
  text-align:center;
}
.main>input[type=button]{
  background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; font:bold 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px 10px; border-radius:5px;
}
#error{
  margin-top:5px;
}
#output{
  background:#000; color:#0c0; text-align:left; padding:5px 10px; margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>index.php</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='xywh'>
      <label for='x'>X:</label><input id='x' type='number' min='0' value='0' />
      <label for='y'>Y:</label><input id='y' type='number' min='0' value='0' />
      <label for='w'>W:</label><input id='w' type='number' min='1' value='1' />
      <label for='h'>H:</label><input id='h' type='number' min='1' value='1' />
    </div>
    <input id='display' type='button' value='Display Areas' />
    <input id='reset' type='button' value='RESET' />
    <input id='add' type='button' value='Add Area' />
    <div id='error' class='er'></div>
    <div id='output'>No Data Requested</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Put your MySQL `connect.php` in a `restricted` folder with permission 700.

```
<?php /* restricted/connect.php */
$db = @new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
?>
```

Let's say you have the following table made in MySQL like:

```
`CREATE TABLE xywh(
   x INT NOT NULL,
   y INT NOT NULL,
   w INT NOT NULL,
   h INT NOT NULL
 )ENGINE=InnoDB;`
```

Now in a folder with the normal permission 755 *(directly in your site root in this case)*

```
<?php /* xywh.php */
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){ // force https or comment out if no https - but why are you making a site with no https?
  header('LOCATION:https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); die;
}
$o = new StdClass;
if(isset($_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'])){
  $x = $_POST['x']; $y = $_POST['y']; $w = $_POST['w']; $h = $_POST['h'];
  $r1 = '/^(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*$/'; $r2 = '/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/';
  if(!preg_match($r1, $x) || !preg_match($r1, $y) || !preg_match($r2, $w) || !preg_match($r2, $w)){
    $o->hacker = true;
  }
  else{
    require_once 'restricted/connect.php';
    $s = $db->prepare('INSERT xywh (x, y, w, h) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $s->bind_param('iiii', $x, $y, $w, $h); $s->execute(); $s->close(); $db->close();
    $o->success = true;
  }
}
elseif($_POST['get_xywh']) && $_POST['get_xywh'] === true){
  require_once 'restricted/connect.php'; $a = [];
  if($q = $db->query('SELECT x, y, w, h FROM xywh')){
    while($r = $q->fetch_object()){
      $a[] = $r;
    }
    $q->close();
  }
  $o->xywh = $a; $db->close();
}
else{
  $o->hacker = true;
}
echo json_encode($o);
?>
```

Note that this is a very crude and simple example. You should have users that  are allowed to input the data. So, you need a login that verifies users first. It's much more work. Also, this example just `INSERT`s a new row no matter if one exists that is the same... which, is what you would want if there is more than one of the same. If not, you'll have to test for sameness with a `WHERE` condition, and do an `UPDATE` if it already exists. Make sure you use prepared statements, unless you are doing very simple queries. Good Luck... this might take a while to understand. It's mostly an AJAX example for you.